# Executar função para vários itens no JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Eu tenho uma função que é responsável por atualizar os valores em algumas `<div>`, segue script:

**file.js**

```
window.onload = function makeRequest() {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            calcPreco(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "_config/buscar_valor.php?id="+document.getElementsByName("cloud")[0].getAttribute("cloudid")+"&periodicidade=monthly", true); // true para asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function calcPreco(preco) {
    console.log(preco);
    preco = preco.replace(",", ".");
    preco -= document.getElementsByName("cloud")[0].getAttribute("desconto");
    document.getElementsByClassName("mostrar_valor").textContent = preco;
}
```

**index.php**

```
<div name="cloud" cloudid="1" desconto="5"> 
<span class="mostrar_valor"></span> 
</div> 
<div name="cloud" cloudid="2" desconto="10"> 
<span class="mostrar_valor"></span> 
</div> 
<div name="cloud" cloudid="3" desconto="15"> 
<span class="mostrar_valor"></span> 
</div>
```

Note que somente os atributos `cloudid` e`desconto` são alterados em cada `<div>`, o resto permanece o mesmo.

O script só fará um cálculo procurando o valor em "** buscar_valor.php **", através do atributo `cloudid`, que é o ID de cada plano.

O atributo `desconto` é o valor que ele subtrairá na conta.

O problema é que ele está fazendo isso apenas para o primeiro `<div>`, como posso fazê-lo funcionar para todas as `<div>`?

UPDATE:

```
window.onload = function calcPreco() {
for(const cloud of Array.from(document.getElementsByName("cloud"))) {
    fetch("_config/buscar_valor.php?id="+cloud.getAttribute("cloudid")+"&periodicidade=monthly")
     .then(res => res.text())
     .then(preco => {
        preco -= cloud.getAttribute("desconto");
        const valor = cloud.querySelector(".mostrar_valor");  
     })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você apenas está a aceder á primeira div com o atributo cloud 
`document.getElementsByName("cloud")[0]`

Em `document.getElementsByName("cloud")` você tem uma lista de  todas as divs, de modo que irá necessitar de um loop para percorrer essa lista.

Exemplo:

```
// aqui guarda todas as divs com o atributo cloud    
var cloud_divs = document.getElementsByName("cloud"); 

// agora vamos aceder uma a uma através do ciclo for
for(let i; i < cloud_divs.length; i++){

valor = cloud_divs[i].getAtribute("desconto");
}

// uma versão mais simplificada
for( el of document.getElementsByName("cloud")){
    valor = el.getAtribute("desconto");
}
```

Comment: @IazyFox...Obrigado pela resposta, foi um amigo meu que montou esse script, eu não tenho muito conhecimento na área ainda. Você pode me mostrar como ficaria essa implementação no código completo?

Comment: Qual é a parte do código que está com dificuldades?

Comment: Eu não sei implementar esses loop na função, não sei como deveria ficar o script.

Comment: A minha resposta esclarece a sua dúvida. Não quero ser malcriado mas acho que você deveria estudar um pouco mais javascript e familiarizar-se com alguns conceitos e mecânicas do mesmo. Se eu chapar aqui o código você não irá aprender nada. De qualquer modo, aqui vão algumas luzes: [Selecionar elementos de uma página](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp) - [Ciclo for](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)

Comment: @IazyFox...Realmente pesquisando consegui fazer algo. Eu consegui fazer ele funcionar de outra forma, parecida com a usa, com base em algumas pesquisas, só não consegui fazer ele imprimir o resultado no <span>, você pode ver o que fiz de errado? Eu atualizei a pergunta.

Comment: Não estou com um computador comigo, mas neste momento só lhe falta  inserir o valor no `span` experimente `innerHTML` ou `innerText`, Ou seja `cloud.querySelector(".mostrar_valor").innerHTML = valorDesejado`

Comment: Perfeito, tem como converter esse valor para virgula, ja que ele vai imprimir com ponto?